# OpenGL - Render to single channel texture?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm trying to render to a single channel texture attached to a framebuffer but its not working. I create the texture using a sized format:

```
glCreateTextures(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, &entityTexture);
glTextureStorage2D(entityTexture, 1, GL_R32F, viewport.size.x, viewport.size.y);
glTextureParameteri(entityTexture, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTextureParameteri(entityTexture, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

UPDATE: I then attach it to my framebuffer together with some others:

```
std::array<GLenum, 4> colorAttachments = { 
    GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, 
    GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, 
    GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, 
    GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT3,
};

glNamedFramebufferDrawBuffers(GBuffer, static_cast<GLsizei>(colorAttachments.size()), colorAttachments.data());
```

Inside the shader I write up top:

```
layout(location = 0) out vec4 gNormal;
layout(location = 1) out vec4 gColor;
layout(location = 2) out vec4 gMetallicRoughness;
layout(location = 3) out float gEntityID;
```

And then write some random test value to it in the fragment shader (drawing a bunch of meshes):

```
gEntityID = 12.3;
```

When I check in RenderDoc the image turns up black with a value of 0. Does all this check out in terms of API usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing to `layout(location = 3) out vec4 gEntityID;` and assigning a vec4 with alpha 1.0 and the single channel value to the red component seems to have done it.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with rendering to a single-channel texture. Your code for routing color outputs to buffers is non-functional.

> ```
> glNamedFramebufferDrawBuffers(GBuffer, 1, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT3);
> ```

That's not [how `glDrawBuffers` or its DSA equivalent work](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer#Draw_color_buffers). Indeed, you should have gotten a compile error, because you tried to pass a prvalue integer literal (`GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT3`) to a function that takes a pointer.

Even if we fix your function so that it passes a single-element array:

```
GLenum attachments[1] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT3};
glNamedFramebufferDrawBuffers(GBuffer, 1, attachments);
```

That still doesn't work.

You pass `glDrawBuffers` an array. The indices of this array are the color numbers you set into your fragment shader. So `location = 3` on the fragment shader output means to look at the 4th element of the array passed to `glDrawBuffers` to figure out which attachment binding point gets used. You only passed one element, since the size you gave was 1. The other elements of the array are set to `GL_NONE`.

So nothing gets written to.

What you (maybe?) want is this:

```
GLenum attachments[4] = {<attach>, <attach>, <attach>, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT3};
glNamedFramebufferDrawBuffers(GBuffer, 4, attachments);
```

Where `<attach>` are the first three attachment points.

Comment: That's my bad for trying to make the example code more concise when pasting to SO, i'm already doing this. I updated the post.